# "Logging" under Configuration and "Application Logs" under Monitor tabs are not available in Wso2 Api manager version 3.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I was trying to configure Logging in WSO2 API Manager version 3.1.0 , But "logging" under configuration tab and "Application logs" under Monitor tab ,these options are not available by default.But in version 2.6.0 these options are available by default as seen in image.

Also there is an option available - "enable logging" under Configure-> Message tracing in wso2 api manager version 3.1.0. when I am trying to enable this , I am getting the error like this-

"Cannot set eventing configuration. Backend server may be unavailable.; nested exception is: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown - An error has occurred. Please refer the logs for more details."

Need suggestions on this.

Monitor tabs images are attached below:

[wso2 apim version 3.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjstV.jpg) 
[wso2 apim version 2.6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMii.jpg)

Comment: Regarding the AxisFault error when enabling message tracing, this is already fixed in API Manager version 3.1.0. Can you please confirm whether the product you are trying out is API Manager 3.1.0 or 3.0.0?

Comment: I am using API Manager 3.1.0 but this issue is still showing in this version.

Comment: Hi Vidya, I tried to reproduce this issue in both API Manager 3.1.0 vanilla pack and 3.1.0 WUM updated pack. But the issue is not reproducible. It works as expected. Have you done any special configurations to your setup? Are you using the WUM updated pack of WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0? Note that in API Manager 3.1.0, we do not have a "Monitor" tab in carbon console. If it is there, that means you are probably using version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple changes in API Manager version 3.1.0 than 2.6.0. Those logging options under configuration and monitor tabs are not available now. Please follow the documentation [1] in order to configure logging with WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0.

The only way to configure logs in version 3.1.0 is via `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j2.properties` file. The log configuration in carbon management console and SOAP APIs are no longer available in 3.1.0.

If you need to view logs, you can use an **external log analysis tool** like Splunk into which you can feed the log files generated inside API Manager logs folder.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/

Comment: So, we can't see logs in the APIM management console in 3.1.0?

Comment: Is there any other alternative to check logs in 3.1.0 APIM console other than checking wso2carbon.log ? because we developers usually checked system logs from management console in previous versions.

Comment: Hi Vidya, I have edited the answer above, with the response.

Answer (score 0):

wso2 3.1.0 don't have carbon for log but have this:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/

and <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j2.properties
is easy and good for working with logs.

for example:

```
# CARBON_LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.type = RollingFile
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.name = CARBON_LOGFILE
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filePattern = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/wso2carbon-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.pattern = TID: [%tenantId] [%appName] [%d] %5p {%c} - %m%ex%n
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.type = Policies
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.strategy.max = 20
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.filter.threshold.level = DEBUG
```

you just need to change this configuration and it work good.

if you want to enable log just change .level=  to:

OFF
FATAL
ERROR
WARN
INFO
DEBUG
TRACE

and you don't need another log app
it's work good.
if you wand find all log in your 3.1.0
you can search *.log in wso2 folder and see all log is available.

Managing log growth with this:

```
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.policies.size.size= 10M
```